# Managed File Field and file_usage_add() - what should I attach the file to?

Tags: 7, forms, files

I'm creating a module which uses the Form API and integrates with the Mantis bugtracker system.  I have included a managed file field on the form and am at the stage of handling the form submission.  The Form API documentation mentions that you must make a call to file_usage_add:

```
Without the call to file_usage_add, file_managed_file_validate produces an error upon saving the form, saying that the uploaded file may not be referenced.
```

Here is the signature for file_usage_add():

```
file_usage_add(stdClass $file, $module, $type, $id, $count = 1)
```

And the explanation of the parameters:

```
$file: A file object.

$module: The name of the module using the file.

$type: The type of the object that contains the referenced file.

$id: The unique, numeric ID of the object containing the referenced file.

$count: (optional) The number of references to add to the object. Defaults to 1.
```

The problem I have is that my module doesn't create any nodes to attach the file to.  I just want to store the file in the filesystem and then send it off to Mantis.

Any suggestions on what I can enter for the $type and $id parameters?

Comment: What about attaching it to user 1?  Are there any problems with this approach bearing in mind that there could be potentially quite a lot of files attached over time?

Comment: Why a downvote?l

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I attached the file to user 1 and can't see any adverse effects as yet:

```
file_usage_add($file, 'mantis', 'user', 1);
```

I also OMITTED the following line from my submit function:

```
$file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
```

This means that the file will be deleted after 6 hours when cron runs.

If anyone has a better solution then I'll be happy to mark as answer.

Comment: I am also not sure how to handle the id on submit or import when the $node id is not available